# What does it mean when a parameter is assigned a value in the function prototype?

Tags: c++

I've just seen this syntax for a function prototype in C++:

`explicit String(unsigned char value, unsigned char base=10);`

I haven't seen this before, but am I right in assuming it sets `base` to 10 regardless of what you call it with?

Comment: @EdKing you said explicit in the question and confused us

Comment: My bad - I've modded the question title :-)

Comment: So `explicit` has nothing to do with anything here?

Comment: That's correct, @John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default parameter, called `base` will take whatever value you send it, or the value 10, if you leave it off, e.g. by calling

```
String(0);
```

Given that you can call it with just one parameter, since the second can be defaulted, a constructor can be marked as `explicit`. This means it won't create a temporary from an `unsigned char` without you noticing, you have to explicitly call the constructor.

Comment: AFAIR, constructors with more than one parameter can be declared as explicit as well to prevent initializer list conversions?

Answer (score 1):

`base` has a default value. You can assign a default value for every parameter, given that all following parameters have default values as well.

`explicit` prevents implicit conversions, so `String k = 0` will not be accepted as valid - it would call `String(0, 10)` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/):

> When declaring a function we can specify a *default value* for each of
>   the last parameters. This value will be used if the corresponding
>   argument is left blank when calling to the function. To do that, we
>   simply have to use the **assignment operator** and a value for the
>   arguments in the function declaration. If a value for that parameter
>   is not passed when the function is called, the *default value* is used,
>   but if a value is specified this default value is ignored and the
>   passed value is used instead.

The [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h1y7x448.aspx) keyword prevents *implicit* conversions:

> C++ ctors (constructors) that have just one parameter automatically
>   perform implicit type conversion. For example, if you pass an int when
>   the ctor expects a string pointer parameter, the compiler adds the
>   code it must have to convert the int to a string pointer. However,
>   this automatic behavior can cause errors.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks - quick and painless.